# Sentry Androdi getMappingFile(): cannot query the value of this property because it has no value

Tags: android, sentry

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/proguard/
I have integrated all the things which are all mentioned in this doc. Whenever i run the task i am getting the following issue
`getMappingFile(): cannot query the value of this property because it has no value`

Comment: What version of the Sentry Android Plugin are you running? What gradle command are you running? And what version of Android Gradle Plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a warning though, the user commented on https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-android-gradle-plugin/issues/29, and it seems to be resolved.